# How to automatically add saved files to directory without restarting - Android Application

Tags: android, restart, file-manager, application-restart

I have created an Android application and save files using the following method:

`File created = new File(dir, time.format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + "." + suffix);`

However, even when the device is connected to my computer, the saved files only appear in the specified directory AFTER restarting the device. How do I force the files to show without restarting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the media scanner. Notice the mime type, you might need to change that depending on the file you are creating

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this.getApplicationContext(), new String[] { filename }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, new OnScanCompletedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(final String path, final Uri uri)
    {
        // Eureka, your file has been scanned!
    }
});
```

Here are some more ways to broadcast a new file:

UPDATE:

```
void alternativeScan(final String filename)
{
    final File file = new File(filename);
    final Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    // New way

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE", fileUri));
    }

    // Keep compatibility

    this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE", fileUri));

    // Usual way

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(fileUri);
    this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And in case still doesn't work, use the next function to check your media storage state

```
public static int getMediaStorageState()
{
    final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        return 0; // All Ok, supported Read & Write
    }
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
    {
        return 1; // Media storage has Read Only state
    }
    else
    {
        return 2; // Something's wrong. No Read/Write access
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't automatically appear in my directory until restarting still =\ .

Comment: I've added to the answer a new function for alternatives scan modes, basically with this you have all possible ways to broadcast a new file in Android. well, there is another one which is to manually (better say programmatically) to insert the record via SQL into the required media table, but I think is overkilling the problem. Also make sure your SD storage is correctly mounted, use the last function in the answer to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dir` is out on external storage somewhere and "only appear" means "only appear when I connect the device to my development machine using a USB cable", [use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to update the `MediaStore` index](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html).

Note that you may also need to do some sort of refresh operation on your development machine, if the development machine's OS (e.g., Windows) caches MTP results.